# How to take video of the inside of a cave, from above, with an action camera?

Tags: gopro

I am interested in lowering a Go Pro Hero 7 into a cave: to record video and to take measurements with two scientific instruments, and want to ask your advice on what would hold the camera.

Specifically, I want to lower in two instruments:  light meter (how much light); air particle meter (how clean the air is).

I estimate the cave would be about 15 feet to 30 feet deep (about 5 to 10 meters). I can lower lanterns in, on ropes, for light.  It’s unlikely that I would go into the cave myself.  Instead I would prefer to stay above on terra firma!

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: What light level are you expecting?  I know nothing about the Hero 7 but have a Nikon P900.  It has a night landscape mode that I have used to take photos in caves that were dimly lit but enough to walk around in without flashlights.  It takes a bunch of exposures and stacks them to take out the camera movement.  I suspect a lot of non changeable lens cameras have the same.

Comment: I would agree with Rose; the camera does not have to be a GoPro.  What I am trying to figure out is how to position the camera so it can take a short video of the light meter and the air quality meter, while all three are "down below".  What would hold each in place, in a certain position?

Comment: My first thought for holding them in a relative orientation is a platform that they are all bolted to.  I suppose you could use struts instead, but a flat plate is very convenient.  Wood is very easy to work with.  If you just want to read the meters a wired interface with the readouts up above can be much more convenient.  It sounds like your problem is experiment design, not photography.  What are you trying to do?  Of course, this is off topic for photography.se.

Comment: If you are using the camera to record the readings on the instruments, the lantern you use to illuminate the faces will corrupt your reading of the ambient light level.  It is much better to use instruments that have a digital interface and record the data somehow.

Comment: thank you very much to Ross Millikan.  these are excellent ideas which i can work on!